# Count the time it takes to retrieve data from the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would measure how long it takes my script to retrieve data from the database so I wrote this code.

```
$Time = time();
$Content = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Content)) {

$UserNick = $Row['UserNickname'];

echo "<div id=\"nickname_users\">".$UserNick."</div>";
$Time2 = time();
$Total = $Time-$Time2;
echo "he employed ".$Total." to retrieve data from the database";
}
```

But he returned 0, so i read "He employes 0 to retrieve data from the database. How can i fix?

Comment: `time()` has a 1 second precision. Try again with `microtime()`.

Comment: Thanks! It works but because the result is negative? -0.00063299999999999 and how can I make sure that does not show the numbers periodicals?

Comment: Invert your math. `$Time2 - $Time` instead of `$Time-$Time2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`time`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns integer, i.e. returns number of seconds since the Unix Epoch.  Depending upon the complexity of your script it's very less likely that your code takes seconds to execute. It is however possible though.

A better solution in this case would be to use [`microtime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) which returns the current Unix timestamp with microseconds.

```
$Time = microtime(true);
$Content = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Content)) {

$UserNick = $Row['UserNickname'];

echo "<div id=\"nickname_users\">".$UserNick."</div>";
$Time2 = microtime(true);
$Total = $Time2-$Time;
echo "he employed ".$Total." microseconds to retrieve data from the database";
}
```

Also, I believe you want `$Time2-$Time` not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function has a resolution of seconds, so if your query returns in less than a second you're likel to get zero as an answer

You should use `microtime()` instead, which has a resolution of microseconds (millionths of a second).

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = microtime(true);
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table`');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $userNick = $row['UserNickName'];

    $total_employed_microseconds = microtime(true) - $start;
    $total_employed_seconds = $total_employed_microseconds * 1000000.0;

    echo "{$userNick} employed {$total_employed_microseconds} microseconds
          and {$total_employed_seconds}";
}

$end = microtime(true);
$total_microseconds = $end - $start;
$total_seconds = $total_microseconds * 1000000.0;

echo "It took {$total_microseconds} microseconds and {$total_seconds} seconds.";
```

Using [microtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) will allow you to be more accurate with your results.  You want to make sure you subtract the start from the end, since the end will always be a larger number. (don't use my variable names)